# React Navigation TypeError: backImage is not a function. (In 'backImage ({ tintColor: tintColor })', 'backImage' is an instance of Object)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, expo

I am following a YouTube tutorial and I got the error. Their snack is not working either and I tried to debug it but I am unable to get anything.

This is the index. js code for the react-navigation.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Image } from 'react-native';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';

import Welcome from '../screens/Welcome';
import Login from '../screens/Login';
import SignUp from '../screens/SignUp';
import Forgot from '../screens/Forgot';
import Explore from '../screens/Explore';
import Browse from '../screens/Browse';
import Product from '../screens/Product';
import Settings from '../screens/Settings';

import { theme } from '../constants';

const screens = createStackNavigator({
  Welcome,
  Login,
  SignUp,
  Forgot,
  Explore,
  Browse,
  Product,
  Settings,
}, {
  defaultNavigationOptions: {
    headerStyle: {
      height: theme.sizes.base * 4,
      backgroundColor: theme.colors.white, // or 'white
      borderBottomColor: "transparent",
      elevation: 0, // for android
    },
    headerBackImage: <Image source={require('../assets/icons/back.png')} />,
    headerBackTitle: null,
    headerLeftContainerStyle: {
      alignItems: 'center',
      marginLeft: theme.sizes.base * 2,
      paddingRight: theme.sizes.base,
    },
    headerRightContainerStyle: {
      alignItems: 'center',
      paddingRight: theme.sizes.base,
    },
  }
});

export default createAppContainer(screens);
```

Comment: Could you post the actual error message

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by making it as a function, changing it to

```
headerBackImage: ()=>(<Image source={require('../assets/icons/back.png')} />),
```